# Udacity sunshine app

Tags: android

I'm going through the Android dev training at udacity.com, following along with the implementation of the Sunshine app. I'm using Android Studio, latest version default installation. API 23.

In forecastFragment.java:

```
    package com.example.asha.sunshine;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * A Forecast fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

        private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

        public ForecastFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater){
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment,menu);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id=item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
                weatherTask.execute("94043");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            //once the root view for the fragment has been created, the listview will be
            //filled with dummy data, like the following, which is like day/weather/high-low

           String[] data = {
                    "Today - Cloudy - 68/43",
                    "Tomorrow - Foggy - 48/23",
                    "Weds - Sunny - 68/43",
                    "Thurs - Rainy - 68/43",
                    "Fri - Sunny - 82/70",
                    "Sat - Rainy - 61/52",
                    "Sun - Sunny - 84/65"

            };

            List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

            // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
            // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
            // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
            //null pointer error because of this
            /*ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    weekForecast); */
            mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    weekForecast);

            //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }


        public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
            private final String LOG_TAG=FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(String...  params){

                // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
                if(params.length==0){
                    return null;
                }

                // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
                // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
                String forecastJsonStr = null;

                String format="json";
                String units="metric";
                int numDays=7;

                try {
                    // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                    // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                    // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                    final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                    final String QUERY_PARAM="q";
                    final String FORMAT_PARAM ="mode";
                    final String UNITS_PARAM ="units";
                    final String DAYS_PARAM ="cnt";

                    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                            .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                            .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                            .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                            .build();

                    URL url=new URL(builtUri.toString());
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                    // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    //Read input stream into a string
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        // Nothing to do.
                        return null;
                    }
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        return null;

                    }
                    forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ForecastFragment", "Error ", e);
                    // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                    // to parse it.
                    return null;
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (final IOException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                try{
                    return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                   Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }


            /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
     * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
     */
            private String getReadableDateString(long time){
                // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
                // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
                SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
                return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
            }

            /**
             * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
             */
            private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
                // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
                long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
                long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

                String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
                return highLowStr;
            }

            /**
             * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
             * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
             *
             * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
             * into an Object hierarchy for us.
             */
            private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                    throws JSONException {

                // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
                final String OWM_LIST = "list";
                final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
                final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
                final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
                final String OWM_MAX = "max";
                final String OWM_MIN = "min";
                final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

                JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
                JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

                // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
                // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
                // properly.

                // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
                // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
                // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

               /* Time dayTime = new Time();
                dayTime.setToNow();

                // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
                int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

                // now we work exclusively in UTC
                dayTime = new Time(); */

                //String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];

                String[] resultStrs = new String[weatherArray.length()];
                for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                    // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                    String day;
                    String description;
                    String highAndLow;

                    // Get the JSON object representing the day
                    JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                    // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                    // "this saturday".
                    long dateTime;
                    // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                    //dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                    dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
                    day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                    // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                    JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                    description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                    // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                    // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                    JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                    double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                    double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                    highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                    resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
                }

                for (String s : resultStrs) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
                }
                return resultStrs;
            }

           /* @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
            if(result != null){
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for(String dayForecastStr : result){
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
            }
            } */
           @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
                if(result != null){
                    List<String> forecastList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(result));
                    forecastList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
                    mForecastAdapter.clear();
                    mForecastAdapter.addAll(forecastList);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is showing error not parsing JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signup to OpenweatherMap.com and u will get api key. u have to use that api key to access the site data like below

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=524901&APPID= past ur apiky here